Power BI Admin API returns 401 Unauthorized when used by Service Principal
We have a Service Principal that we want to use to do bunch of Administrative tasks in PBI Service like archiving unused reports etc.
We've created an App Registration on Azure side and I'm successfully able to use it to generate an Access Token

When using token in a regular API calls I'm getting some data back

However, when using this token in Admin API calls I'm getting 401 Unauthorized

We've attempted two things:

Assigning all Power BI Service related API permissions like "Dataset.ReadWrite.All", "Tenant.Read.All" etc. in App Registration itself (ignore red line on screenshot :D)



Assigning Service Principal to "Fabric Administrator role"  (before doing that we've removed all API permissions as noted here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-get-groups-as-admin "When running under service principal authentication, an app must not have any admin-consent required permissions for Power BI set on it in the Azure portal.")


Both scenarios netted the same result - 401 Unauthorized.
SP is part of a group that is listed under "Service Principals that can use Fabric APIs". Under same group we have Azure Data Factory SP that we're using to run Dataset refreshes and this is working fine.

Do you have the correct Fabric tenant settings. In the Fabric admin portal there are 2 sections which allow service principals to use APIs.
One for "developer" APIs and one for "Admin" APIs. If access was enabled for the former, but not the latter, it would explain what you have described.
Service Principal API settings in Fabric Admin portal
